# How to show or print all the parts in an OrCAD library (OLB) file?

Tags: schematics, library, orcad

I have a .OLB file for OrCAD schematic where there are multiple part in.

I an open the .OLB file using File => Open => Library, and I can also successfully place parts in a design.

From previous work I know that it is possible to print all the part on a single page, with each part in a frame.

How to show or print all the parts in an OrCAD library (OLB) file?

Comment: Printing a picture of library parts doesn't really seem to hold much water in terms of the "hidden" data that each library part contains (not printable) so what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I am auto generating OrCAD library symbols, and want to inspect that the pinout at each part is as expected for placing and naming, and that all the relevant parts are included.  For this it is very handy to have a single PDF page with all the parts, since PDF allows zooming so the text can still be read in the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive trial and error, and some Google work, I found the solution:

1. Start Orcad Capture.
2. Select menu File => Open => Library, and select the .OLB file.
3. Double click the part symbol (AND gate) to open first part of symbol.
4. Select menu View => Package to show all parts in package.

Then printing will show all the parts each in a box.